# apache .htaccess url rewrite condition is causing 404 message

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^VIN/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?action=vin&view=$1&vin=$2
```

I can go to my url (foo.com) and it works just fine.  However, if I go to foo.com/VIN/vinDetails/12345, I get a 404 error.

I'm new to the URL re-write, and have looked everywhere to try and figure this out, but I keep coming up short.

Comment: Try: `foo.com/VIN/vinDetails/12345/` with a trailing slash

Comment: That worked... is there a way to catch that in the rule?  Also, my CSS/js/jpe?g.... line isn't working... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make trailing slash optional:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^VIN/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=vin&view=$1&vin=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

css/js loading is due to your use of relative paths. Make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
**Otherwise** You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: I added the <base href="/"> in the head section and it loaded the css.  I even double checked every css file for @import, url(, src=, ../, and ./ and fixed those too...

Now, however, my javascript isn't working.  any way to tell htaccess to make all javascript loads happen from the root dir (/)?

Comment: `<base href="/" />` is for all the `css/js/image` files. If `js` isn't loading then rest in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and check in Networking tab what are 404 URLs you're getting.

Comment: to start off - the thing that looks most troublesome to me are the 10 lines in the console saying "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://foo.com/VIN/vinDetails/css/[Files 1-10].css"

Comment: Figured it out... the <base href="/" /> MUST be before any requests are made... not just anywhere in the <head>

Comment: Yes that's why I wrote add it **just below** the `<head>` section.